# Compare two Unstructured Data Columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

My database table has two varchar fields of 2000 max.

**Comment1** and **Comment2**

Both the fields large volume of contain unstructured data.

The situation is that all Comment1 data might be present in Comment2 field.

I am looking for a SQL query or function that will help me to compare these 2 unstructured data fields such as I can find matches where some or all data of Comment1 lies in Comment2

For eg:
Suppose Comment1 contains the data :

**Hello, My name is xyz. I work in abc company. I work as a Manager.**

Comment2 field contains :

**Hello, My name is xyz. I work in abc company. I work as a Manager. My responsibility is to maintain records. I manager two seniors.**

Here we see that all or some of data of Comment1 lies within Comment2. Hence, I should find a match on comparison.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that is possible in a reliable way.

Comment: Use the INSTR function?

Comment: Could you be more specific about how comments should be compared ? What does it mean exaclty `some of data of Comment1 lies within Comment2` ? Which part of comment1 must match - one specific word, or two consecutive words, or maybe any single letter (even a space) ?

Comment: Hi Kordirko, As shown in my example.. there can be multiple words of Comment1 that can match Comment2. I see that Comment1 data is present in Comment2 field. If Comment1 field has 'My name is Rikin' then that sentence needs to be searched within the Comment2 field which can contain more information than just 'My name is Rikin' Hope I am able to explain. Let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do a case insensitive search for each sentence contained within `comment1` and test whether it is also within `comment2` then (assuming you have a field to uniquely identify the row):

```
WITH sentences AS (
  SELECT ID,
         LEVEL AS sentence_position,
         UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR( comment1, '[^.]+(\.|$)', 1, LEVEL ))) AS sentence
  FROM comments
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( comment1, '[^.]+(\.|$)' )
)
SELECT *
FROM   comments c
WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                FROM   sentences s
                WHERE  s.id = c.id
                AND    INSTR( UPPER( c.comment2 ), s.sentence ) > 0 );
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c7e3/16/0)

If you want to break it down further then you can split `comment1` into words (rather than sentences) and search based on that if you want; you just need to modify the regular expression to `'\S+\s'` and it will split on words. However, I do not think that that would be particularly valuable unless you are then looking to aggregate word matches and require a threshold of matching words (since matching on a single word is, most of the time, likely to not be significant).

**EDIT:**

This will split a table containing multiple `comment1` fields into sentences and then compare them to a separate table containing `comment2` fields. It's not particularly efficient (but if you were looking for efficiency then you would probably want to pre-process the `comment1` fields to separate them into sentences/words and put those into a separate table).

```
WITH ids AS (
  SELECT comment1,
         REGEXP_COUNT( comment1, '[^.]+(\.|$)' ) AS num_sentences
  FROM   comment1s
),
sentence_ids AS (
  SELECT LEVEL AS sentence_number
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( SELECT MAX( num_sentences ) FROM ids )
),
sentences AS (
  SELECT comment1,
         sentence_number,
         UPPER(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR( comment1, '[^.]+(\.|$)', 1, sentence_number ))) AS sentence
  FROM   ids i
         INNER JOIN
         sentence_ids s
         ON (i.num_sentences >= s.sentence_number )
)
SELECT c.comment2, s.comment1, COUNT(1) AS number_of_matched_sentences
FROM   comment2s c
       INNER JOIN
       sentences s
       ON ( INSTR( UPPER( c.comment2 ), s.sentence ) > 0 )
GROUP BY comment2, comment1
ORDER BY number_of_matched_sentences DESC, comment2, comment1;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32fa3/21/0)

Comment: Hello MT0, Thank you for your help. This looks helpful. However, my two fields comment1 and comment2 are located in two different tables and there is no unique id to identify the two (I am hoping we can create an id for both tables). Can you help me modify your code to run that fits my condition. Thank you once again

Comment: Added an edit that may help meet these different requirements.